# how to update multiple rows, which satisfy different condition

Tags: mysql

i want to update multiple rows, which satisfy different condition

```
Result
Student_No  Subject_No Marks

ST101         SU03     69
ST102         SU01     3
ST101         SU04     45
ST101         SU05     87
ST103         SU01     44
ST103         SU03     50
ST103         SU01     56
ST108         SU01     78
ST105         SU05     98
```

i want Increase marks of all subjects by adding the increment as given below:
Rang     Increment
0-24          8
30-36          7
44-54         5

Thanks.
Shan

Comment: Result
Student_No Subject_No Year_Exam Marks
ST101 SU03 1 69
ST102 SU01 1 61
ST101 SU04 1 70
ST101 SU05 1 87
ST103 SU01 2 51
ST103 SU03 1 59
ST103 SU01 3 56
ST108 SU01 1 78
ST105 SU05 2 98

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most natural way to do this is with a case statement:

```
update Result
    set Marks = Marks + (case when Marks between 0 and 24 then 8
                              when Marks between 30 and 36 then 7
                              when Marks between 44 and 54 then 5
                              else 0
                         end);
```

You can also do this with a `join`, which might make it easier to add in new ranges:

```
update Results join
       (select 0 as lb, 24 as ub, 8 as inc union all
        select 30, 36, 7
        select 44, 54, 5
       ) ranges
       on Results.Marks between ranges.lb and ranges.ub
    Results.Marks = Results.Marks + ranges.inc;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE MARKSTABLE
   SET MARKS=MARKS+IF(MARKS BETWEEN 0 AND 24, 8, IF(MARKS BETWEEN 30 AND 36, 7, IF(MARKS BETWEEN 44 AND 54, 5, 0)))
```